# How to use saveChildModel() in Yii

Tags: yii

How to use saveChildModel() in Yii where we can save the property of child model class.

Comment: What's saveChildModel()? Yii doesn't have such method.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a saveChildModel() in the yii documentation.

But if you're asking how to save a model that is related to another model you could try the following.

If you have two models, User and Post with the following relation:

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{   
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
                'post'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Post', 'postId'),
        );
    }
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
$myUser->post->save()
```

[Yii tutorial on relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

Hope this helps!